# How to upgrade ubuntu 18.04 to 18.10?

Tags: apt, 18.10

set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.

Comment: Please note that upgrading from LTS to non-LTS is usually bad idea. With LTS you can live without problems for 5 years. If you need new drivers - then wait for HWE (newer kernel and xserver for 18.04 LTS).

Comment: from 18.04 LTS to 18.10

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the **Software & Updates** app
2. Tap the **Updates** tab
3. Find the section titled **Notify me of a new Ubuntu version**
4. Set **For long-term support versions** to **For any new version**
5. Click **Close**

Then try update Ubuntu again.